# Cassandra CQL: Unable to insert

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

This is my query

```
insert into a1('name',age') values ('dinesh's',12);
```

I can't insert the value using Cassandra CQL.

How to remove Cassandra escape character using PHP Cassandra CQL method?

Comment: your age missing a single quote? also, have you tried \ to escape?

Comment: It does need escaping, but it's `''` in CQL and SQL, not `\'`

Answer (score 14):

To escape single quotes in CQL you double them up, e.g to enter the string `dinesh's` you write `'dinesh''s'`.

See [similar question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201108.mbox/%3C20110803152250.294300@gmx.net%3E) on the mailing list:

Comment: Why they use a second single-quote to escape the first one? using slash as the escape character is very common, why to use such unconventional form?

Comment: It seems to be for consistency with SQL, which also uses doubled single-quotes for escaping - see the brief discussion [here](http://grokbase.com/p/cassandra/user/1183fqfd64/cql-how-to-escape-single-quotes) for example

Comment: That's right. Maybe because sql driver I have used manages ' in the text when I insert string using placeholders, I never had a problem there.